# Как сохранить свой рисунок на PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qrcode

Прошу помочь. `QR` код выходит на экран. но как сохранить это рисунок на рабочий стол

```
import sys
import qrcode
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QStatusBar, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(472, 502)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 81, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 40, 301, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 341, 321))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 80, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 472, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВВЕДИТЕ ТЕКСТ:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЕНЕРАЦИЯ В QR КОД"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СОХРАНИТЬ QR CODE"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СБРОСИТЬ"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.qrcode)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.sbrosit_vse)


    def qrcode(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        img = qrcode.make(text)
        qr = ImageQt(img)
        pix = QPixmap.fromImage(qr)
        self.label_2.setPixmap(pix)


    def sbrosit_vse (self):
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.label_2.clear()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

> pixmap : QPixmap
>
> Это свойство содержит растровое изображение метки.

> bool QPixmap::`save`(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr, int quality = -1) const
>
> Сохраняет растровое изображение в файл с заданным именем файла,
> используя указанный формат файла изображения и коэффициент качества.
> В случае успеха возвращает true; в противном случае возвращает false.

```
import sys
import os
import qrcode
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, \
    QPushButton, QStatusBar, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(472, 502)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 81, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 40, 301, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 341, 321))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 80, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 472, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВВЕДИТЕ ТЕКСТ:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЕНЕРАЦИЯ В QR КОД"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СОХРАНИТЬ QR CODE"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СБРОСИТЬ"))


class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.qrcode)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.sbrosit_vse)    

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.save_qr_code)                         # +++   

    def qrcode(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        img = qrcode.make(text)
        qr = ImageQt(img)
        pix = QPixmap.fromImage(qr)
        self.label_2.setPixmap(pix)

    def sbrosit_vse (self):
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.label_2.clear()        
        
    def save_qr_code(self):
        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        file_name = self.lineEdit.text()
        
        if file_name:
            path = os.path.join(current_dir, file_name + '.png')
            self.label_2.pixmap().save(path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Process finished with exit code 1073741845

Comment: Сразу программа закрывается  с этой ошибкой

Comment: @Handsome_777 я вам очень советую всегда запускать приложение из CMD/консоли/терминала и вы всегда получите реальную ошибку. Вы запустили мой пример?

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!